# How to remove all requests from Telegram Bot database (getUpdates)

Tags: php, telegram-bot

hello my bot continue sending message to me.
my code is:

```
while(true)
{
    header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
    $token= "MY-TOKEN";
    $url= "https://api.telegram.org/bot".$token."/getUpdates";
    $update = file_get_contents($url);
    $arrayUpdate= json_decode($update, true);
    foreach ($arrayUpdate['result'] as $key) {
            $chat_id = $key['message']['from']['id'];
            $command = $key['message']['text'];
    }
    if($command == "/start"){
        $text= "starting...";
        $url= "https://api.telegram.org/bot".$token."/sendMessage?chat_id=".$chat_id."&text=".$text;
        file_get_contents($url);
    }
}
```

my bot send me message infinity i want my bot to send me message when i use it then stop and wait for next request.

Answer (score 5):

Your problem is that you put your code that checks for updates in a infinite `while` loop. So you get infinite messages. To fix that:

- Manage "offsets" of updates. Every update has a unique id number called `update_id`. Every time an update gets received, its `update_id` equals `update_id` of the last messages + 1 (Every time an update arrives, its `update_id` gets increased by one).  You can ask bot api to get only updates that has a `update_id` bigger than or equal what you specify, by passing `offset` when executing `getUpdates`:
  This is one example, using GET:

  `api.telegram.org/bot<TOKEN>/getUpdates?offset=<UPDATE_ID>`
  Save the `update_id` of the last message you received. Add it by 1. Next time when you ask for updates via `getUpdates`, pass this new `update_id` as `offset` as shown above (or via POST). And api will bring you the next message received. Also, when you use offset to get new messages, old messages *get deleted*. They can't be obtained using `getUpdates`.
- Process only the last message you receive, not all of them. Currently, you are processing all messages received in one request. But this way you would process old message more than once. So just process the last one and let the api delete the last message for you in each request.
- Messages saved in `getUpdates` queue will eventually get empty as every old message gets deleted in each request. Don't forget to take care about such situation.

More info about `getUpdates`:  [API Documentation](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#getupdates)